# How do i concatenate and cast a int to a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

im having trouble figuring out the syntax to concatenate and cast to a string to following section of code

```
 new_prod_list2 = list(map(lambda x:x str(['product_id'])) + x['product_category'] + x['product_name'] , products))
print(new_prod_list2)
```

Product_category and product_name concatenate, but when i try to concatenate product_id (which is a int) using str to convert it to a string, i keep getting errors.

Would anyone mind helping me with this problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean `str(x['product_id'])` instead of `x str(['product_id'])`? In general it looks like your parentheses might be mismatched, did you want to concatenate `str(x['product_id']) + x['project_category']`?

Comment: @j1-lee if you are so lazy you could have typed _\[mre]_ instead of _reproducible example_

Comment: " did you want to concatenate str(x['product_id']) + x['project_category']" Yes

Comment: i have tried to put the x in front of str as shown below but i get this error "IndentationError: unexpected indent"

Answer (score 0):

Bring the `x` that's right after the colon in the `lambda` expression into the `str()` call, so that the `['product_id']` item access gets invoked:

```
 new_prod_list2 = list(map(lambda x: str(x['product_id']) + x['product_category'] + x['product_name'] , products))
```

And the more Pythonic way to do this would be to use list comprehension and string formatting:

```
new_prod_list2 = [f'{x["product_id"]}{x["product_category"]}{x["product_name"]}' for x in products]
```

Comment: i have tried to put the x in front of str as shown below but i get this error 'str' object is not callable"